# How to use more than two refiners methods for one refiner in a webpart for Sharepoint Online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, refiner

Hello I am tasked with reproducing an already existing sharepoint online doc library site. The search refiner methods need to have more than one type: "Multi-Checkbox" and "Product Feature Fancy Tree". However when I edit the page each refiner configuration in the web part settings seems to allow only one method. One or the other. I have seen sites that had both; where there is a "checkbox" next to each refining option and the "tree" as well.

Attached is how it should look. It has a twisty for the "Tree" and the "searchbox". When I go to the search criteria on the page it only has a twisty for the "tree" not a checkbox like shown in the screenshot.

[image: With both the "tree" and "checkbox"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no OOB method to display refiners with multi-checkbox in a tree view.

You need to create your own custom Refiner Display Template to achieve that.

The templates are located in: Master Pages -> Display Templates -> Filters

Learn more about [creating custom refiner control Display Templates for SharePoint](https://www.eliostruyf.com/creating-custom-refiner-control-display-templates-for-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: Ok I don't know what OOB means but thank you there were customizations.  :)